# how to check a html form input is an integer or not

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script>
var y = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    alert(y);
    if (Number.isInteger(y)) {

    } else {
        document.getElementById("quantity").style.borderColor = "#e60000";
        document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;enter valid quantity.*";
        document.getElementById("quantity").focus();
    }
</script>
```

I need to validate a quantity field in a HTML form. but when I put any value in quantity like number, text or whatever, program always run in else part of this code. it's not working for an integer.

Comment: you have a syntax error in your code

Comment: how about using parseInt(y,toYourBase)?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of achieving the same. Some of them are mentioned below:

1. Use Pattern `<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" />`
2. Use Number field `<input type="number" min=0 max=100 step=1>`
3. Use `isNan` to verify if input is a number `isNaN(y)` and also verify if integer by using `y.indexof(".")==-1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a textbox input for the quantity, the `value` of that textbox will always be a string. Check using [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

```
var y = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

if (!isNaN(y)) {
  console.log('is a number');
} else {
  document.getElementById("quantity").style.borderColor = "#e60000";
  document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;enter valid quantity.*";
  document.getElementById("quantity").focus();
}
```

`isNaN` returns whether the given value is *Not a Number*. So, if it goes into the `if` block, you know that the string is a number. You can then convert it to real integer using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

Comment: @pro.mean -- I didn't understand. Why `y` would not be defined? `value` will always return a string, an empty string if no value is specified. As long as the quantity textbox is available, `y` will never be undefined.

Comment: what if a user explicitly set value `undefined` and then check this code? we must make our code foolproof.

Comment: try `isNaN(e)` . where `e` is not defined at all

Comment: no. my code will not break anything. give me example how it will break. in your code what is the value of `isNaN(0/0)`

Comment: try that. we need to add one additional check in this case, even in your code too. do not argue try to learn.

Answer (score 1):

1. convert given value to the number using [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
2. now check with [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) method .

   ```
   const quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
   const qty = document.getElementById("qty");
   let y = quantity.value;

   let numberY = Number(y);

   if(isNaN(numberY)) {
    console.log('This is not a number');
   } else {
     console.log('do it now. it is a number');
     quantity.style.borderColor = "#e60000";
     qty.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;enter valid quantity.*";
     quantity.focus();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just compare it with a number

```
 if(y != "" && y - y == 0) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
<script>
var y = document.getElementById("quantity").value; 
    if (!isNaN( parseInt(y) ) ) {

    } else {
        document.getElementById("quantity").style.borderColor = "#e60000";
        document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;enter valid quantity.*";
        document.getElementById("quantity").focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: did you mean `parseInt()`